# Converting simple script from actionscript2 to actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I am a beginner in as3 and 've been following a simple flash sketchpad script, here's the link > http://www.sitepoint.com/create-flash-sketchpad/ . It's coded in as2 but I want to convert the codes to as3.I 've been trying to convert them to as3 but I just can't seem to make it work. I would deeply appreciate it someone could help me.

```
createEmptyMovieClip("Line",1);
Line.lineStyle(3,0x000000,300);

onMouseDown = function () {
    Line.moveTo(_xmouse, _ymouse);
    onMouseMove = function () {
        Line.lineTo(_xmouse, _ymouse);
    } 
}

onMouseUp=function() {
    onMouseMove=null; 
}
```

Comment: Share what you tried as well, & we will help you correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give in AS3:

```
var Line:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(Line);
Line.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000, 1);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    Line.graphics.moveTo(e.stageX, e.stageY);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    Line.graphics.lineTo(e.stageX, e.stageY);
}

function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I decided to create an entire working example, so you can understand how this works;

```
package {
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Martyn
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite {

        public var draw:Shape = new Shape();

        public function Main():void {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

            trace("init");
            addChild(draw);
            draw.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x000000, 300);

        }
        private function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
           stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
           draw.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
           trace("onMouseDown");
        }

        private function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
            trace("onMouseUp");
        }

        private function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            draw.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
            trace("onMouseMove");
        }

    }

}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I am trying to understand this now.Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @p ppt - no problem. If you don't quite know why I declared some of the code inside init(), it's just to make sure that the class has access to a reference to the stage when the class adds event listeners and invokes addchild(); You'll find other topics on using an init function.